# Even Odd Pattern on an array where I output the sum

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
Write a function that takes an array/list of numbers and returns a number.

See the examples and try to guess the pattern:

even_odd([1,2,6,1,6,3,1,9,6]) => 393
even_odd([1,2,3]) => 5
even_odd([0,2,3]) => 3
even_odd([1,0,3]) => 3
even_odd([3,2])   => 6    




def even_odd(arr):

    count = 0
    index = 0
    length = len(arr)


    while index < length:
        for num in range(len(arr)):
            if arr[index] % 2 != 0:
                count += arr[index]
                index += 1
            else:
                count *= arr[index]
                index += 1
    return count
```

So basically the pattern is multiply the first 2 numbers and add the third and I set it to where for each index value if it it was the first number I would add it to the count to keep track and then multiply it with the second number and then add the third. I passed 3/4 sample cases except for one which was the first one ---> even_odd([1,2,6,1,6,3,1,9,6]) => 393. I am just wondering what is the flaw with my logic and does anyone have a better way to solve this that is efficient and clean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a challenge on Codewars (https://www.codewars.com/kata/559e708e72d342b0c900007b), so maybe you should use this platform to discuss solutions with other competitiors, instead of Stackoverflow.

The main point of this challange is to investigate the calculated pattern and not the code itself.

If you know the required pattern, the code is easy (Spoiler!):

```
def even_odd(arr):
    num = 0
    for i, e in enumerate(arr):
        if (i % 2) == 0:
            num += e
        else:
            num *= e
    return num
```

Answer (score 0):

This produces the desired results:

```
from operator import add, mul


def even_odd(nums):
    acc = nums[0]  # accumulator
    ops = [mul, add]
    i = 0
    for num in nums[1:]:
        acc = ops[i](acc, num)
        i = 1 - i  # alternates between the two operators
    return acc
```

Comment: I haven't got that far yet in learning python but that is some nice syntax and a great solution